# Mac OS: fastest way to list files of directory and get sizes

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, unix

I need to list all files of a directory and get their sizes (including resources forks, ...)

I was wondering about the best (fastest and accurate) way to get this information.
Should I use carbon functions, darwin unix methods (ftw, stat, ...) or NSWorkspace/NSFileManager methods?

Thanks for your help

Comment: On the criterion of “fastest”: In the modern era, pure time-to-completion doesn't matter as much as responsiveness. A non-blocking solution that takes five seconds to get everything will feel faster, by letting the user get back into things faster, than a solution that blocks for two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSWorkspace/NSFileManager methods to get your programming going, they are reasonably fast and even more importantly, fit into the Cocoa environment is such a way that developing with them will be fast.

If, after you get your program going, you find that they aren't fast enough (and I mean, you notice lag and you have determined by using Shark/Instruments that those exact methods are causing the slowdown), then you could consider other means.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Good advice generally, but NSFileManager doesn't include resource forks in its size reporting.